# Do `validator` methods need to check required arguments are required?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

From the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) it seems that this code contains an extra check in the second `validator`-decorated method of `password1`being in `values`.

Am I correct in that observation - as `password1` does not contain a default value it is indeed required and so should be there?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator

class UserModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    password1: str
    password2: str

    @validator('name')
    def name_must_contain_space(cls, v):
        if ' ' not in v:
            raise ValueError('must contain a space')
        return v.title()

    @validator('password2')
    def passwords_match(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        if 'password1' in values and v != values['password1']:
            raise ValueError('passwords do not match')
        return v
```

OK, reading on in the docs I see: *If validation fails on another field (or that field is missing) it will not be included in values, hence if 'password1' in values and ... in this example.*

May I see an example of what this means? Does this mean that I need to always check for the existence of values if they play some role in my validation even if they are required?

Comment: Also -- it is unclear why there is a `v.title()` returned instead of v in the method? What is the purpose of what is returned? I guess the return value is only used if the method is accessed directly at the class level /shrug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I see an example of what this means? Does this mean that I need to always check for the existence of values if they play some role in my validation even if they are required?

Yes, if you're using a preceding field, you always need to consider that it might be missing from `values`. This is because the validator will always be called, even if an earlier field had an error (including a required field which is missing).

> Also -- it is unclear why there is a v.title() returned instead of v in the method? What is the purpose of what is returned?

The value is changed so `samuel` would become `Samuel`, this is included to demonstate that validators can modify values as well as raise errors.

Comment: Brilliant. I like that convention. Thank you.